# I'm trying to build an endless looping vertical slider that loops seamlessly and I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I need to build a looping vertical slider, it needs to seamlessly go from the first slide to the last and it keeps getting stuck and is quite jarring. and I can't seem to get it right. I'll have my code attached below any help would be amazing.

CSS

```
        .carousel-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
}

.carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: transform 1s;
    will-change: transform;
}

.carousel-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #f44336;">Item 1</div>
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #2196f3;">Item 2</div>
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #4caf50;">Item 3</div>
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #ff9800;">Item 4</div>
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #9c27b0;">Item 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
const itemHeight = items[0].offsetHeight + 15; // Include the margin-bottom
let currentItem = 0;

function moveCarousel() {
    if (currentItem >= items.length - 1) {
        currentItem = 0;
        carousel.style.transition = 'none';
        carousel.style.transform = `translateY(0)`;
        setTimeout(() => {
            carousel.style.transition = 'transform 1s';
            moveNext();
        }, 50);
    } else {
        moveNext();
    }
}

function moveNext() {
    currentItem++;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateY(-${itemHeight * currentItem}px)`;
}

setInterval(moveCarousel, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your method for transitioning the items is to translate the whole carousel, an easy way to handle this would be to simply append copies of the items each time the carousel moves.

#### Working snippet:

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
const itemHeight = items[0].offsetHeight + 15; // Include the margin-bottom
let currentItem = 0;

function moveNext() {
  carousel.append(items[currentItem % items.length].cloneNode(true))
  currentItem++;
  carousel.style.transform = `translateY(-${itemHeight * currentItem}px)`;
}

setInterval(moveNext, 3000);
```

```css
.carousel-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
}

.carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: transform 1s;
    will-change: transform;
}

.carousel-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #f44336;">Item 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #2196f3;">Item 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #4caf50;">Item 3</div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #ff9800;">Item 4</div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: #9c27b0;">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```